# JQuery Find() не находит нужный элемент в ответе $.ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax

Добрый день!

Есть галерея на сайте, по нажатию на кнопку "Загрузить ещё" должна происходить дозагрузка фотографий без перезагрузки страницы. Написал такой скрипт:

```
    $(".loading_more_instagram").click( function() {
    $this = $(this);
        //вот это просто эффект на кнопке
    if($this.hasClass("focus")) {
        return false;
    }
    $this.addClass("focus").text($(this).data("load"));


        //А вот пошёл сам запрос
    $.ajax(
        "адрес скрипта отдающего следующие 12 фотографий для загрузки",
        {
            data: {
                arParams: window.arParams, //Передаём массив параметров 
                max_id: $(this).data("max_id"),
                max_tag_id: $(this).data("max_tag_id")
            },
            type: "POST"
        }
    ).done(function(data) {
        $(document).find(".look_instagram_pop .clearfix").remove();

                //вот тут ответ есть
        console.log($(data)); 
                //а тут уже undefined
                console.log($(data).find(".look_instagram_pop").html()); 

    //По идеи добавляем к ранее загруженным фотографиям новые 12 фоток  

$(document).find(".look_instagram_pop").append($(data).find(".look_instagram_pop").html());

     //А вот это кстати срабатывает
     $this.replaceWith($(data).find("span.loading_more_instagram"));

        });
    return false;
});
```

Непонятка состоит в следующем:

Когда я вывожу `console.log($(data));`, т.е. весь ответ скрипта, я вижу всё, что мне нужно:

[image]

Вот что тут есть:

[image]

Но как только я обращаюсь к `console.log($(data).find(".look_instagram_pop").html())`, в ответ получаю пустой объект (без `html()` то же самое):

[image]

Ума не приложу, почему так происходит. Ведь в `$(data)` уже пришло всё, что мне нужно. В общем, помогите, кто чем сможет. )

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Используйте .filter() вместо .find()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, тут действительно 2 варианта, т.к. получаемые в `date` теги находятся "на одном уровне", то `find()` начинает искать в первом из них и ничего не находит. Для того чтобы это обойти, нужно воспользоваться  `.filter()`, как написал [xfloooo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/24385/xfloooo), либо в шаблоне обернуть все элементы общим контейнером div, тогда будет работать `jquery find()`.